# ID for each ImageView in ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-pageradapter

First of all, i am quite a newbie to android and java as i come from a web developer background.

Recently, i had try to develop and app for learning purposes, but i am facing one headache problem during the development process.

i had a main activity that triggers Asynctask to get the list of id's from my wamp database through a php file.

Part of my main activity file - login_main.java

```
public class login_main extends AppCompatActivity implements OnDataSendToActivity{
    ViewPager viewPager;
    CustomAdapter adapter;

    ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        String username = pref.getString("username", null);

        String type = "getProfileImages";

        RetrieveData retrieveData = new RetrieveData(this);

        retrieveData.execute(type,username);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    }


    public void sendData(String response) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
            for (int i = 0 ; i < result.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = obj.getString("image"+i);
                String url = "http://192.168.12.252/"+id+"/profile.png";
                images.add(url);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(login_main.this,images);//set ur image array here
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

AsyncTask file

```
public class RetrieveData extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
    Context context;
    RetrieveData(Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }
    private OnDataSendToActivity dataSendToActivity;

    public RetrieveData(Activity activity){
        dataSendToActivity = (OnDataSendToActivity)activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String profile_url = "http://192.168.12.252/getprofile.php";
        String image_url = "http://192.168.12.252/imagelist.php";
        String type = params[0];

        if(type.equals("getProfile")){
            try {
                String user_name = params[1];
                URL url = new URL(profile_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result = null;
                result = bufferedReader.readLine();
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else if(type.equals("getProfileImages")){
            try {
                String user_name = params[1];
                URL url = new URL(image_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("Image", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("Image", "UTF-8")+"&"+URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result = null;
                result = bufferedReader.readLine();
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dataSendToActivity.sendData(result);
    }
```

Page Adapter file

```
public class CustomAdapter extends PagerAdapter{
    Activity activity;
    ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList<>();
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> images){
        this.activity = activity;
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view==object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe,container,false);

        ImageView image;
        image = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);


        DisplayMetrics dis = new DisplayMetrics();
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dis);
        int height = dis.heightPixels;
        int width = dis.widthPixels;
        image.setMinimumHeight(height);
        image.setMinimumWidth(width);
        try{
            Picasso.with(activity.getApplicationContext())
                    .load(images.get(position))
                    .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .into(image);
        }catch (Exception ex){

        }

        container.addView(itemView);
        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View)object);
    }
}
```

So let me explain a little bit here, whats going on here. What my app does is it will get array of ids from my phpmysql, after it get from asynctask, it send the data back to main activity using Interface which is the sendData function in main from that sendData function you can see there is a loop to loop through each id and generate a url image link and store it into a string array which the variable name is images and the page adapter will put the image into imageView in the page adapter with Picasso pluggin.

```
try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
            for (int i = 0 ; i < result.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = obj.getString("image"+i);
                String url = "http://192.168.12.252/"+id+"/profile.png";
                images.add(url);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(login_main.this,images);//set ur image array here
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The problem is i want to make those image clickable and when it click, it will display the information for that particular id, how do map the id with those image and make them clickable and when it clicks , it do another asynctask to retrieve more detail information of that id

Comment: Inside your Adapter, set a [Click Listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) on `image`. Then you can call the AsyncTask in `onClick()`.

Comment: @SammyT The problem im facing here how do i pass the id over together with the image to the adapter

Answer (score 0):

You can alter your Adapter class to take in an ArrayList of Ids as well:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends PagerAdapter{
    ArrayList<String> mIds = new ArrayList<>();

    public CustomAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> images, ArrayList<String> ids){
        mIds = ids;
    }
```

Then, inside your `instantiateItem()`:

```
image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        String clickedId = mIds.get(position);
        // Do something with the selected image Id
    }
});
```

Don't forget to change your call to `new CustomAdapter(activity, images, ids)` though.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you create your own Object (Class) that have item (id, filename, ...). Pass your `ArrayList<YourObjectName>` into `CustomAdapter`.